# Cross-referencing elements with their label in asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm currently writing a document with asciidoctor, and I need to link images and sections within the document. While I understand how cross reference in asciidoctor works, I was wondering if there is a way for me to link elements like sections and images displaying also the element number that asciidoctor generates with the :sectnums: attribute. In this example you can better see what I wish to achieve, without typing it manually:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not possible yet... See issue: [#858: Add possibility to use figure number or text in link text](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/858)

---

There is an approach discussed in [#1381: Attributes reference is not replaced in anchors](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1381):

```
[#system_overview,reftext='{figure-caption} {counter:refnum}']
image::system_overview.png[]
```

---

The solution I use for the moment is to post-process the produced HTML with some java code based on JSoup. Of course this doesn't work with the PDF backend.

Comment: Yeah I've figured out that some work with extensions would be necessary, and found out that PDF doesn't support that. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: I think that the approach described in #1381 is pretty much what you want to do. It should work with PDF and HTML backends.